# Medicinal chemistry: adding substituents to increase/decrease activity

Tags: drugs, medicinal-chemistry

In medicinal chemistry, it is possible that adding 2 different substituents does not increase the activity of the drug much when added separately, but when added together, the activity is increased a lot. An example of this was for the drug sorafenib.

But my question is can the other way around happen? Where 2 substituents increase the activity of a drug separately, but when added together, the activity of the drug is now slowed.

Regarding aromatic rings:
The classic examples for activators and deactivators are in regards to aromatic rings and in regards to increasing/decreasing pH and on whether they were put on ortho/para or meta positions. But my question isn't limited to just aromatic rings and for pH as a variable. But my question for that is - can 2 substituents that are both activators or both deactivators, and both on either ortho/para position or both on meta position, can 1 still increase activity or still decrease activity, when all else is the same?

Anyways, the classic example of sorafenib is as follows. It was shown to be slow activity with a phenoxy substituent, and with a isoxazole ring, but when both were bonded to "it" at the same time, showed an increase in activity. Where "it" is a urea that was bonded to a paramethylbenzene.  Thanks.

Comment: I would argue that, if starting with a single scaffold, there will be a "sweet spot" with regard to numerous ADME properties (eg Lipinski's rules) as you add/subtract groups. However the optimum will be potentially very different from the properties that optimize in vitro protein-drug interactions.

Comment: @BuckThorn my topic is about QSARs. Quantitative structure-activity relationships. Since your Google search link is for "drug reactions" that is less-specific than my topic, I fail to see how your phrase is better than mine. If you feel it is feel free to explain to me why that is.

Comment: I am simply asking for clarification but I admit my comment was a bit dense. You are evidently starting with one molecule and making modifications. Consider then your example, sorafenib. It is evidently an enzyme inhibitor, so you need to consider both ADME and how it binds to its target. Regarding the target binding, the effect of modifications depends on complementarity with the active site. Imo it would be difficult to generalize whether removals, additions or modifications help without consideration of what the target looks like, but someone else might have the detailed answer you seek.

Comment: A concrete example: https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/31146197/

Comment: @BuckThorn my question has more to do with synergism and contraindications. For example, 2 acids can never go in the basic direction when added together or 2 bases when combined go in the acid direction, but it's not the case with this in medicinal chemistry on activities. This was technically a "yes/no" question and in other places I asked, I got the answer "sure why not" but I didn't explicitly ask for examples. If I did that this question may be shut down quicker.

Comment: In any event activity is measured on some uM the greek letter for mu. So 1.7uM is 10x faster than 17 uM. I realize I have a question regarding that. Now, regarding a false analogy, if by chance I saw 2 acids will act as a base if used together, I'm just asking if the "other way around" can happen. So so far in other chemistry forums, someone replied "sure why not."

Comment: I took up your example of sorafenib because it makes it easier to discuss the question. IMO there is nothing wrong with bringing up concrete examples as you did to make a question clearer. // Drug activity in micromolar units is not a measure of how fast a compound acts but rather of the dose (concentration) required for a certain result, for instance inhibiting a target enzyme.// Take sorafenib again. You can modify it this way or that and find that different modifications, taken one at a time, enhance binding, but some combinations taken two at a time decrease binding....

Comment: ... whereas other paired combinations do the opposite. This is not surprising at all, because the effect depends on the size, shape, and chemical composition of the enzyme pocket where the molecule is binding.

Comment: BTW activity may be measured in "unit" units: https://www.biomol.com/resources/biomol-blog/guide-to-enzyme-unit-definitions-and-assay-design This is not the same as "u" used to mean "micro", as in micromolar. The article I linked to discusses the IC50 of the drug in micromolar concentration.

Answer (score 1):

**Drug chemistry is complicated: simple patterns are not the norm**

For a drug to be effective it must meet many criteria, some simple and some very complex.

Bioavailability, for example, depends on the route of delivery and even this is sometimes complicated. Orally delivered drugs (eg analgesic pills) have to survive the stomach and also have to be absorbed into the body from some part of the digestive system. This may not be easy to achieve. Sometimes even small changes in a molecule will vastly alter its absorption, stability in the digestive tract or active concentration in the body. Sometimes small changes may make the molecule far easier for the body to metabolise, greatly lowering the bioavailability. And those things are the simple side of the problem.

Many drugs work by inhibiting specific enzymes. Here the problem gets even more complicated. Good inhibitors need to match and bind to an active site in a specific enzyme. Sometimes similar molecules will have some activity for a specific target and similar variants will have similar activity. For example, there are structural similarities between the commonest NSAIDs, paracetamol (acetaminophen), aspirin, ibuprofen and naproxen (they all inhibit the cyclooxygenase enzymes, though the details differ).

But enzyme active sites are complex 3D structures and the specific details of the active site, which will determine whether a specific molecule can bind to it, are far from simple. Sometimes a very small changes in the molecule makes a huge change to the binding ability potentially making the drug either less or more effective. Multiple changes can have synergistic or contradictory effects. And it isn't easy to work out why as we often don't know the actual structure of the key binding site or sometimes even which enzyme is the target.

So pharma firms, when they find something that works a bit, tend to get their chemists to make a wide range of slightly modified molecules and test them all *in vivo* in the hope some will be better.

It isn't simple and there are often no clear reasons why one molecule works better than another molecule. The variety of 3D structures (of drugs or binding sites) is very large and, especially when the target site is poorly understood, impossible to predict what modifications will work.

And these two considerations ignore another important constraint: whether a specific molecule will cause other side-effects by interaction with some other target.

Given all the constraints, it is not a surprise that it is hard to predict whether a molecular modification will have an effect that is good or bad. and you probably should not expect clear patters in most cases.

Comment: When you said "Many drugs work by inhibiting specific enzymes" why? Why would a drug need to prevent an enzyme from binding to a receptor? I thought majority of drugs is to bind to a receptor.

Comment: @NealConroy Perhaps I oversimplified. Some drugs *activate*, some *inhibit* enzymes (or proteins in general). The way drugs do that is to interact with receptor *sites* on enzymes (sometimes activating something, sometimes blocking something).